# Thevenin Theorem seems to not work in this 1 bit RAM RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, circuit-analysis, ram

I have a problem which consist in 1 bit RAM made of 3 MOSFETs. One of the questions is to calculate the maximum voltage that the memory element can receive. I have obtained the result by inspection (it is 4 Volts) but I'm unable to reach the same by applying the Thevenin Theorem.

My understanding is: I have a circuit made of several resistors and one capacitor (which is the memory element). If the circuit is reduced to a \$ (V_{TH}, R_{TH}) \$ Thevening Equivalent, and given that the capacitor behaves like an open circuit for long periods of time (it's fully charged), I can assume that the maximum voltage the capacitor might have is \$ V_{TH} \$. The problem is that the \$ V_{TH} \$ I find has nothing to do with the expected result (4 Volts).

**I want to know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem by applying the Thevenin theorem.**

The exercise, along with all my schemas and equations, are below:

[image]

In a previous question I have calculated the parasitic resistance and it is \$ R_{PA} = 185.347405560882 \$ TeraOhms.

The question I actually need to answer is:

> Now, suppose the drain of  Q1  is high, and the store line is held at the same voltage as the drain of  Q1 . What is the maximum voltage, in Volts, that the gate of  Q2  can be charged to? Note, this value must be larger than  VOH = 3.5 Volts  to satisfy the static discipline.

Now, my 'Tehevening Equivalent' attempt to find the voltage in Q2 is below:

[image: Replacing capacitors by the corresponding RON resistors]

[image: Circuits to calculate VTH and RTH]

$$
parallel(R_{1}, R_{2}) = \frac{1.00000000000000}{\frac{1.00000000000000}{R_{1}} + \frac{1.00000000000000}{R_{2}}}
\\
R_{\mathit{TH}} = {\rm parallel}\left(R_{\mathit{PA}}, R_{\mathit{ON}} + {\rm parallel}\left(R_{\mathit{OFF}}, R_{\mathit{PU}}\right)\right)
\\
I_{\mathit{TH}} = \frac{V_{S}}{R_{\mathit{PU}} + {\rm parallel}\left(R_{\mathit{OFF}}, R_{\mathit{ON}} + R_{\mathit{PA}}\right)}
\\
e = -I_{\mathit{TH}} R_{\mathit{PU}} + V_{S}
\\
\mathit{ITH}_{2} = \frac{e}{R_{\mathit{ON}} + R_{\mathit{PA}}}
\\
V_{\mathit{TH}} = -\mathit{ITH}_{2} R_{\mathit{ON}} + e
$$

Or in `SageMath`/`Python`:

```
V_S = 5.
R_ON = 2100
R_OFF = 110e6
R_PU = 10e3
R_PA = 185.347405560882e12

parallel(R1, R2) = 1./(1./R1 + 1./R2)

R_TH = parallel(R_PA, R_ON + parallel(R_OFF, R_PU))

I_TH = V_S / (R_PU + parallel(R_OFF, R_ON + R_PA))
e = V_S - I_TH * R_PU
I_TH2 = e / (R_ON + R_PA)
V_TH = e - I_TH2*R_ON
```

The final result (`V_TH`) I get is `4.99954549553765` Volts, and it should be 4 Volts.

Comment: In the schematic from the question, there are **two** \$R_{PU}\$ resistors. Your schematics have only one, why?

Comment: Because the second R_PU is after the mosfet's gate, so is not connected to my equivalent circuit (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I think the answer is that when Q3 reaches some voltage, `Store` disconnects until Q3 discharges a bit, in which case `Store` connects again, therefore keeping Q3 at a 'controlled' voltage. So the Thevenin Equivalent is not valid for this circuit since `Store` connects/disconnects depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Assuming 'infinite' Roff below Vth, Is it not simply Vs - Vth?

Comment: If you apply Thevenin, yes. Well, there is a small voltage divider due to Roff, but hardly modifies the original voltage. The thing is that V_TH won't reach 5 volts since `Store` won't allow it (V_gs will be less than V_t)

Comment: I understand what you mean by 'disconnects and reconnects' now. You mean Drain-Source resistance goes up as Gate voltage goes below the threshold voltage, and so 'regulates' the Drain-Source voltage drop to ~1V. This is correct, but your wording is confusing.